# Why doesn't this lifetime bound cause an error?

Tags: rust

This code compiles and work, but according to my understanding, it should not compile:

```
use std::fmt::Display;

pub fn test<S>(s: S)
where
    S: Display + 'static,
{
    println!("test: {}", s);
}

fn main() {
    let s = String::from("string");

    test(s);
}
```

The lifetime of variable `s` is in `main`, but the function `test` has a bound that `S` must be `'static`. I think the lifetime of variable `s` must be `'static` or larger than `'static`. What's wrong with my reasoning?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bound `S: 'a` means that any references contained in `S` must live at least as long as `'a`. For `S: 'static`, this means that references in S must have a `'static` lifetime. The `String` type doesn't hold any references (it owns its data), and therefore the code compiles.

Quoting [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-02-advanced-lifetimes.html#lifetime-bounds):

> Types without any references count as `T: 'static`. Because `'static` means the reference must live as long as the entire program, a type that contains no references meets the criteria of all references living as long as the entire program (since there are no references).

If you call the function with `test(&s)` instead, [compilation will fail](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=78e489dddee00528af7167cb47491d10&version=stable):

```
error[E0597]: `s` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:14:11
   |
14 |     test(&s);
   |           ^ does not live long enough
15 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
```

Here, `S` is `&'a String` for some lifetime `'a`, and the lifetime bound requires that `'a` must be `'static`, which isn't the case.